# Comparison between SOCP and SDP in terms of computational complexity

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, second-order-cone-programming

Dears

If I have an optimization problem with n variables and m constraints that can be solved using the SOCP and SDP, how can I compare the performance of both algorithms using the Big-O notation? I know that SDP is far more complex than SOCP but I would appreciate it if you can break it down for me.

Comment: You first have to define what algorithms you are comparing, listing the generic problem classes are not enough (although they would have somewhat similar complexity if using the ellipsoid algorithm, but that would really not be interesting as it is not a relevant strategy in practice)

Comment: Thank you Dr.Johan for your reply. I have a previous reply of you in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2337838/why-are-sdps-more-expensive-than-lp-or-socp
in which your have stated that complexity of the SDP is O(m^3) however, the complexity of SOCP is O(nXm). However, I would appreciate it if you can elaborate more about these two complexities. What are the operations that demand O(m^3) complexity in SDP and what are the operations that demand O(nXm) in SOCP? I would  appreciate it if you can recommend a reference that discusses these issues with simple examples to visualize them.

Comment: Why SDP contains $O(m^3)$ operations when you have (dense) LMI constraints of size $m$ is described in the answer, and it does not talk about SOCPs at all. The answer there still applies: read a paper on an implementation (such as sedumi or sdpt3) to get the basic operations required. There is no single answer, it depends on the algorithm, implementation, and properties of the problem. SDP is normally more expensive as checking feasibility of an iterate requires checking for psd which is cubic complexity, while a quadratic constraint can be checked in linear time.

Comment: I understand. However, I'm a bit confused. How does a solver like Mosek deal with the SOCP constraints (like x>=y^2 or x^2+y^2<=constant or xy>z^2+p^2) in a more efficient way than dealing with a SDP-based problem if both the SOCP and SDP have the same complexity! I remember that your previous answer states clearly that we solve an SDP if the problem is really an SDP due to its complexity. Maybe I'm missing something. Also, does the storage demands of the SDP makes it less efficient than LP and SOCP problems?

Comment: SDP and SOCP do not have the same complexity. Already checking feasibility is cubic vs linear complexity, as I said above (but then there are many other parts in an algorithm that might dominate the cost, once again depending on algorithm, implementation, problem structure). Storage is another point where an SDP might be much worse.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking more questions but can you elaborate on the storage bottleneck of the SDP in comparison to SOCP?

Comment: The constraint in an SOCP is a vector, while it is a matrix in an SDP, hence obviously more expensive if they are of the same size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131362/discussion-between-engfrompalestine-and-johan-lofberg).